# Need oracle query for this output

Tags: sql, oracle

```
sno mappingtype username

1      A            xx   
2      B            yy   
3      A            aa    
4      B            bb
```

Above is my table... i want oracle query for the following result

**sno mappingtype username**

```
1     A           xx    
                  aa    

2     B           yy
                  bb
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why `yy` is not `2 B`?

Comment: And how `2 B` became `aa`?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some code. We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: sorry.. this is the output
sno mappingtype username

1     A           xx    
                  aa    

2     B           yy
                  bb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a SQL version. (Maybe you want an sqlplus trick, but you don't asked for it)

```
with a as (
    select 1 sno, 'A' mappingtype, 'xx' username from dual union all
    select 2 sno, 'B' mappingtype, 'yy' username from dual union all
    select 3 sno, 'A' mappingtype, 'aa' username from dual union all
    select 4 sno, 'B' mappingtype, 'bb' username from dual
    )

    select 
        case when rnk=1 then sno end as sno,
        case when rnk=1 then mappingtype end as mappingtype,
        username
    from(       
        select 
               sno, 
               mappingtype, 
               username, 
               row_number()over (partition by mappingtype order by sno) rnk
        from a
        );
```

Comment: thank u so much florin ghita

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be like this:

```
select min(sno) , mappingtype, username from yourtable Group by mappingtype, username
```

Comment: with a as (
    
    select serlnumb sno, matyname, servuscd username from SS_GB_SERVUSER_DTLS where usercode = 'SYSTEM' and usersess = '1369C36F'
    )

    select 
        case when rnk=1 then sno end as sno,
        case when rnk=1 then matyname end as matyname,
        username
    from(       
        select sno, matyname, username, row_number()over (partition by matyname order by sno) rnk
        from a
        );

THIS IS MY QUERY... WHEN I EXECUTE IT, MY SERIAL NO IS: 1 2 3 8.... WHY THE SERIAL NO CHANGES?

Answer (score 0):

Tring florin ghita code, the output was like this :

[image: the original code]

so, making some changes to the code it could be like this:

```
WITH a AS (
         SELECT 1 sno, 'A' mappingtype, 'xx' username  FROM dual
        WHERE TYPE = 'A' AND username = 'xx'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 2 sno, 'B' mappingtype, 'yy' username  FROM dual
        WHERE TYPE = 'B' AND username = 'yy'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 3 sno, 'A' mappingtype, 'aa' username  FROM dual
        WHERE TYPE = 'A' AND username = 'aa'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 4 sno, 'B' mappingtype, 'bb' username   FROM dual
        WHERE TYPE = 'B' AND username = 'bb') 

        SELECT CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN sno END AS sno,
       CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN mappingtype END AS mappingtype,
     username
     FROM (SELECT sno,
           mappingtype,
           username,
           ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY mappingtype ORDER BY sno) rnk
         FROM a);
```

and the output will be the same in Shalim question :

[image: after coding]

Comment: with a as (    
    select serlnumb, matyname, malecode, servuscd, stardate, stopdate, remarkss, actvdesc  
 from SS_GB_SERVUSER_DTLS
WHERE usercode = $P{sUserID}
and  usersess = $P{sSessionID} 
    )

    select 
        case when rnk=1 then serlnumb end as serlnumb,
        case when rnk=1 then matyname end as matyname, 
 malecode,
        servuscd, stardate, stopdate, remarkss, actvdesc
    from(       
        select serlnumb, matyname, malecode, servuscd, stardate, stopdate, remarkss, actvdesc, row_number()over (partition by matyname order by serlnumb) rnk
        from a
        )

Comment: i have used the above query... serlnumb is not in order... its in order 1 2 3 8

Comment: Could you explain what exactly your query has to do, I don't understand the logic of it